# Building a tree in C# and fill it with recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

I have to build a tree, similar as filesystem structure of files and folders in the hard drive.
Instead of files and folders I have folders, and equipments.

I have created this class

```
public class TreeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? IdParent { get; set; }
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public bool IsEquipment { get; set; }
    public List<TreeModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of N root which can have childrens of TreeModel elements.
I have tryed this recursive function which makes the program crash

```
 private TreeModel GetChild(TreeModel tree, ref List<ShipSparePartsCategory> folders, List<ShipSparePartsCategory> equipments)
    {
        if (tree == null)
        {
            return tree;
        }

        var combined = folders.Concat(equipments);
        
            var nodes = combined
           .Where(x => x.IdParent == tree.Id && x.IsActive == true)
           .Select(y => new TreeModel()
           {
               Id = y.Id,
               IdParent = y.IdParent,
               Name = y.Name,
               Level = y.Level,
               IsEquipment = equipments.Any(z => z.Id == y.Id) ? true : false,
               Children = equipments.Any(z => z.Id == y.Id) ? new List<TreeModel>() : new List<TreeModel>(),
           })
           .ToList();

            tree.Children.AddRange(nodes);
       

        return GetChild(tree, ref folders, equipments);
    }
```

I have no idea how to fix it and call it in the correct way.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: What show the crash's report?

Comment: It says Access violation

Comment: Access Violation? strange... show us on what line. I don't see why this code could fail with an access violation.

Comment: It says iisexpress.exe ended up with "Access violation" code